# Update of dask's dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dask

I'm new to dask so could you help me please?
I have a csv-file like this:

```
id,popularity,hashtag,seen
0,100,#footbal,0
1,200,#2017,0
2,300,#1,0
```

and somehow i managed to get a dask dataframe `hashtags_to_update`:

```
id  seen
0   118
2   136
```

I'd like to merge a data from `hashtags_to_update` with data from csv-file to get:

```
id,popularity,hashtag,seen
0,100,#footbal,118
1,200,#2017,0
2,300,#1,136
```

For now I'm doing the following

```
hashtags_df = dd.read_csv('path/to/csv/file').set_index('id')
hashtags_df["seen"] = hashtags_df["seen"].add(hashtags_to_update["seen"], fill_value=0).astype('int64')
hashtags_df.compute().to_csv('output.csv', sep=',')
```

But as far as I know there are some problems when the data contains strings which are casted as python's objects, so there will be no parallelism because of GIL.

Is there anything you could advice me to do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use multiprocessing (thus avoiding the GIL).

there are several ways:

setup a client (by default it will ensure multiprocessing):

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
```

or

```
import dask.multiprocessing
dask.config.set(scheduler='processes')  # overwrite default with multiprocessing scheduler
```

according to the documentation the Former is recommended.

more info:

[Client](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduling.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20#dask-distributed-local)

[dask.config.set](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduling.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20#local-processes)

Comment: Excuse me, but could you please explain in some more details? If I understood correctly, this technique 'replaces' threads with local process to avoid GIL problem. But I'm not sure what should I do after I set scheduler='processes'.

Comment: the rest of your code stays the same.
you can look at the dask dashboard (if you have bokeh installed and using the client) and see that you are actually running in parallel.

Comment: MRocklin has put a great video about working with the dask dashboard:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_GqzcuGLCY&t=814s

Comment: Oh, I see. And, for example, if I want only a part of code, which is about working with DF I mentioned before, to work with multiprocessing, not threads, I should wrap it in `with dask.config.set(scheduler='processes'): ... `. Am I right?

Comment: yes.
read this [Configuration](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduling.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20#configuration)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!