# dask: specify number of processes

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to use dask to do some embarassingly parallel processing. For some reaason I have to use dask but the task could be easily achieved using `multiprocessing.Pool(5).map`.

For example:

```
import dask
from dask import compute, delayed

def do_something(x): return x * x

data = range(10)
delayed_values = [delayed(do_something)(x) for x in data]
results = compute(*delayed_values, scheduler='processes')
```

It works, but apparently it uses only one process.

How can I configure dask so it uses a pool of 5 processes for this computation?

Comment: Have you tried `results = compute(*delayed_values, scheduler='processes', num_workers=5)`?

Comment: I just tried that, it didn't work. The keyword was just ignored.

Comment: That's interesting. It seems to work for me and the code looks fine. I don't think I can help you beyond here. Sorry mate :\

Comment: Thanks, anyway. Are you sure `num_workers` made any difference? As I said, it did run, but using just one process, so I cooncluded it `num_worksers` was ignored - I put a `time.sleep` into the task instead of multiplication to make sure I can see how many processes are running.

Comment: Yes, there was a difference, though I validated using the task manager (I'm on windows). By default, if I left out `num_workers`, the task would utilize 12 processes (depends on your CPU), but when I specifically specify `num_workers`, then I saw the delta of processes as the value I set for the parameter. I also increased the `data = range(10000)` during my test.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Apologies! I did something wrong when I checked first time, I tried again now and I can see the speedup. Thank you very much. Would you like to turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `num_workers` parameter to specify the number of processes for the `compute` method.

```
results = compute(*delayed_values, scheduler='processes', num_workers=5)
```

Answer (score 5):

you can configure it to use a custom process pool as such:

```
import dask
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

dask.config.set(pool=Pool(5))
```

or as a context manager:

```
with dask.config.set(scheduler='processes', num_workers=5):
    ...
```

you may want to read this [dask_scheduling](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduling.html?highlight=multiprocessing)

or my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262480/update-of-dasks-dataframe/51262806#51262806)

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me - I get an `ImportError: No module named config` when I try to import dask.config. I guess it's because my version of dask, 0.17.1 is too old?